# Dymola data processing

Tags: modelica, dymola

I want to seek a good data processing method of Dymola from you。I have the following needs：

1.Record the simulation data after each model change to achieve the purpose of comparison. Because the model is complex, I don't want to simulate repeatedly every time. My current solution is to use "export result". The disadvantage is that when I open Dymola again, I can't select variables with diagram(Select variables as shown in the following figure), which makes it particularly troublesome for complex models to find corresponding variables with variable Browser.[image]

2.When the amount of data is large (more than 20000), better data observation effect can be achieved (as shown in the figure below)[image][image]

3.In data processing, variable integrals in different time ranges can be calculated to achieve the purpose of comparison

I probably have these three needs, of which the third point is the most important. Acceptable methods are: Dymola itself, Excel, origin or MATLAB. Because it is not to draw beautiful drawings for writing papers, simplicity is the most important. As for data processing with Dymola, I recently found the answer in the "user manual", but I still haven't found a better method.
Thanks to those who can browse or answer my questions, I hope to find a simple data processing method.

Comment: For question 1. if you translate the model again and then load the result file that uses that model the Dymola diagram on the Simulation page works as expected.

Comment: Dymola also ships some Matlab scripts that can be used to interact with Dymola and for pre- and post-processing of the files, they are here: `C:\Program Files\Dymola 2022x\Mfiles`. If you want to do batch simulations and/or extensive processing of large amounts of data, then I would recommend Matlab (or really python instead of Matlab).

Comment: The python_interface files are here: `C:\Program Files\Dymola 2022x\Modelica\Library\python_interface`. Inside the `doc` directory, open `index.html` to learn what you can do and how. Matlab can also call python code: https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-python-libraries.html

Answer (score 1):

You could try the Testing library shipped with Dymola. Functions for creating reference data are included and you can create tests only for the signals that you want to compare, keeping the result file sizes small.